# How to Inject no interface, external library classes into JavaEE application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, mocking, cdi

I am fairly new to JavaEE and also the concept of dependency injection. However I do have a fair understanding of it even though I do not know all the ways it can be used.

I have a Local Interface as below:

```
@Local
public interface MyInterfaceLocal {
    SomeType getMeSometype();
}
```

The class that implements this interface is stateless EJB.

```
@Stateless
public class MyInterfaceImpl {
    public SomeType getMeSomeType() {
        //Some implementation details...
        ExternalLibraryClass externalLib = new ExternalLibrary(arg1, arg2);
        return externalLib.externalLibMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, how can I avoid instantiating the `externalLib` and let this be injected in someway? For example if this was another EJB that I created with an interface, then I could simply let the EJB container handle the instantiation, with an `@EJB` annotation like below.

```
@Stateless
public class MyInterfaceImpl {
    @EJB
    AnotherInterface anotherInterfaceImpl;

    public SomeOtherType getMeSomeType() {
        //Some implementation details...

        return anotherInterfaceImpl.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do (something like) this for external library that I am using because, that allows me to:

1. Change the underlying external library that is currently being used with minimal change to my code-base. May be change to a better one if need arises.
2. Easily inject a mock when I want to unit test the `MyInterfaceImpl` class.

I have so far looked at-

1. Creating a wrapper method whose parameter is the `ExternalLibrary` and thus can perform some kind of manual method parameter injection. This still makes my implementation tightly coupled to the underlying library. (Or I am not doing it right)
2. Using `Context & Dependency Injection` container to do the injection (like how the EJB container does. I am aware its not the same). Researched about the ability of using `Producers`. Although I understand what `Producers` do with respect to CDI, I am not able to wrap my head around how I can make use of this? Or even if I am on the right path?

**UPDATE:**
I found a few articles that helped me understand the CDI Producers better and I tried going by that approach but faced another problem. So now I have:

**ExternalLibraryProducer.java**

```
public class ExternalLibraryProducer {
    @Produces
    private ExternalLibraryClass1 extrnalLibraryClassProducer() {
        return new ExternalLibraryClass1("SomeString", 7);
        //The constructor actually takes a string and another commplex type 
        //as parameters. I am keeping it a little simple here.
        //I am trying to set the ExternalLibraryClass1() arguments 
        //programmatically at runtime.
    }
}
```

Now the constructor of the object that I want to produce, takes in parameters, lets say a String and integer. I thought I could create a `Qualifier` to pass in these parameters to produce the object that I want.

**ExternalLibraryClass1Qualifier.java**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface ExternalLibraryClass1Qualifier {
    String argument1();
    Int argyment2(); //This is actually another complex type. Keeping it 
    //simple here.
}
```

Now what I want to do is, I want the argument values to be set programmatically at runtime (assume, from a properties file). And I am not able to figure out how to do this. So my final injection would look like below.

```
@Stateless
public class MyInterfaceImpl {
    @Inject
    @ExternalLibraryClass1Qualifier(argument1 = "something", argument2 = 7)
    ExternalLibrary externalLib;

    public SomeType getMeSomeType() {
        //Some implementation details...
        return externalLib.externalLibMethod();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: CDI producer looks like good approach although qualifier arguments won't do the trick here - the injection point wouldn't match the producer method I think. Maybe invert the approach and have `argument1` and `argument2` stored somewhere where the producer can look while creating the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDI producers are a way to go here, the only question is, how exactly do you want to build them.

Since you said that the arguments come from a property file, I would suggest that you invert the approach and let producer method check that property file and extract the values (or ask any "reader" which did that before and caches it):

```
@Produces
private ExternalLibraryClass1 produceExternalLibraryInstance() {
    // read the properties from the file or from any cache you use
    String arg1 = PropertyReader.getarg1();
    Integer arg2 = PropertyReader.getArg2();
    // create object with those args
    return new ExternalLibraryClass1(arg1, arg2);
}
```

With this you obviously need no qualifier and can then simply do `@Inject ExternalLibraryClass1`.

Just note that producer will be invoked based on when you create an object which injects `ExternalLibraryClass1` - make sure you can grab the args from property file this soon. (should't be trouble when produces does the reading, might be trickier if you have some cache in place)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your producer method for `ExternalLibrary` accepts arguments which you will be needing for the object creation, and you can have these arguments produced through CDI producesr.

```
public class ExternalLibraryProducer {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    public ExternalLibraryProducer() {
        // set name and age from properties file or elsewhere
        // or you can set them individually on their respective producer methods, but might be costly considering you need to read the properties file twice
    }

    @Produces
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @Produces
    public int age() {
        return age;
    }

    ....

    @Produces
    private ExternalLibraryClass1 extrnalLibraryClassProducer(String name, int age) {
        // Or you can use them directly here, if you opt to not separate this config from the dependencies
        return new ExternalLibraryClass1(argument, age);
    }
}
```